# Music for relaxing mind?

Tags: electronic-music, classical-music

After several hours work, sometimes a math book to concentrate, sometimes trivial admin stuff, I feel my brain disturbed, seems a voice or many voices is whirling inside.

Could you pls recommend some music to relax? Pls recommend only music, not songs with lyrics. Maybe some classical music or electronic music? But pls don't be limited to these two.

Comment: Are you asking for music to listen to while doing something else or to listen to on break?

Comment: Welcome to the site athos. Unfortunately, what is determined "relaxing" is in the ears of the beholder so as of now I'm closing this question as primarily option based. If you can supply more objective criteria we can reopen this question.

Comment: @JacobSwanson something to have a 10-15 mins break so that my mind get all the noise/voices inside wiped out and refreshed!

Comment: @athos  I would recommend either 30's-40's jazz or classical.  It really depends on your tastes though.  You can look at Spotify's playlists by genre and pick one you like.

Comment: look into music used for biofeedback sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is a bit opinion based, but here are a few I would recommend:

Yo Yo Ma & Bobby McFerrin, ["Air on a G String"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CcnDi67qaI)

Yo Yo Ma - ["Soledad"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=az2BiQffOXw)

[Pachelbel's Canon in D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOA-2hl1Vbc)

[Palestrina - Sicut Cervus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0yd5EE0hAB8)  (technically, this does have lyrics, but they're in Latin)

Turtle Island String Quartet - Because

[Apocalyptica - "Nothing Else Matters"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-B8k0n_3cs)

[Faure - Pavane](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mpgyTl8yqbw)

[Pavane - Jazz version (Regina Carter)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vhhg6kra9ao)

Answer (score 3):

If you into electronic then i can suggest to check out CHVRCHES new single called "Leave a trace" they have great beat and also awesome lyric! For classical one, if you know Yiruma--he had a great album that you can listen, I suggest "First Love [Repacked]". It's his popular album. But I personally like his latest album called "Blind Film". Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I don't want lyrics as subconsciously my mind will try to understand it. but I'll try Yiruma, thank you!